# Why does Go deadlock with "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep"

Tags: go, channel

Here's the relevant excerpt from my code:

```
func main() {
    quit := make(chan int)

    readyQueue := make(chan Proc)
    runQueue := make(chan Proc)
    waitQueue := make(chan Proc)

    procList := getInitialProcList()
    fmt.Println(procList)

    for _, proc := range(procList) {
        switch {
            case proc.Status == READY:
                readyQueue <- proc
                tick(quit, readyQueue, runQueue, waitQueue)
            case proc.Status == RUN:
                runQueue <- proc
                tick(quit, readyQueue, runQueue, waitQueue)
            case proc.Status == WAIT:
                waitQueue <- proc
                tick(quit, readyQueue, runQueue, waitQueue)
        }
    }

    <-quit // blocks to keep main thread alive
}

func tick(quit chan int, readyQueue chan Proc, runQueue chan Proc, waitQueue chan Proc) {
    select {
    case p := <-readyQueue:
        fmt.Println(p)
    default:
        fmt.Println("[tick] nothing in ready queue")
    }

    select {
    case p := <-waitQueue:
        fmt.Println(p)
    default:
        fmt.Println("[tick] nothing in wait queue")
    }

    select {
    case p := <-runQueue:
        fmt.Println(p)
    default:
        fmt.Println("[tick] nothing in run queue")
    }

    quit <- 0
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` on the line `readyQueue <- proc` in the above code.

Comment: What are the channels for if you do not use goroutine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as the code shows, you are never firing up a concurrent reader for any of the channels you create. Because they are unbuffered, any writes to them, will block until someone, somewhere reads from the other end. This is not the case in your code.

If `tick` is supposed to be the consumer, you should fire it up before going into the loop.
And it should then have a loop itself, so it keeps polling the channels for new values.

```
go tick(quit, readyQueue, runQueue, waitQueue)

for _, proc := range(procList) {
    ....
}
```

Another immediate solution would be to create all the channels with a buffer of 1.

```
quit := make(chan int, 1)

readyQueue := make(chan Proc, 1)
runQueue := make(chan Proc, 1)
waitQueue := make(chan Proc, 1)
```

While this will solve your immediate problem, there are still some other potential issues with your design. We would need to know exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish, in order to give a more well rounded answer.

Comment: Jimt got in too fast. Additionally the select statements  in the tick func aren't going to work as written - you probably want a single select statement and a for loop.  Finally you need to close the various channels after you're done sending.